# InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement - Google Autocomplete with Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, autocomplete

I'm trying to add a Google Autocomplete field in Wordpress, to my functions.php file.

I've added this code:

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    if (is_page ('9')) { 
        ?>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var input = document.getElementById('autocomplete');
                var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'initAutocomplete');
```

autocomplete is the id of an a field within an HTML object.

```
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete"
         placeholder="Enter your address"
         type="text"/>
</div>
```

I'm getting this error back:

**InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement**

I've made sure that it's an actual input field. Am I just wrong in the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

```
function initAutocomplete() {
    if (is_page ('compost-intake-form')) { 
        ?>
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&key=API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
                $(function(){
                  var complete;
                  var input = $("#autocomplete")[0];
                  complete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                });
            });
            </script>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'initAutocomplete');
```

The [0] is to select the HTML element out of the variable.

[Got it from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54574718/places-api-autocomplete-form-fields-not-working?rq=1)